I am facing an issue from making build of an app in flutter
Try to build an flutter app
i am trying to build an app i am trying flutter build appbundle command and i am facing this issue
error :
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 1136 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "fa-solid-900.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 419720 to 2552 bytes (99.4% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Awais.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Awais.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             69.2s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
F:\appdevelopment\abduallah\vet>

try inspecting the packages you installed from your pubspec.yaml file.
Please find the package that you used before encountering the 'build failed with an exception'
You can also see how you import that package in your dart class, you should be able to identify which produces conflict.

TIPS: Maintain a proper import and use of packages supported for cross-platform such as path_provider instead of path_provider_android (if you are planning to not focus only on mobile platform development/production). You must always read the changelog to stay informed about the package you used.

Most of the time, you may encounter build failed issues due to the deprecated source code or built-in class implementation. Including the misalignment of the version supported with the package you used.
Hope it helps.
